# How to disable chrome developer tools automatic network recording?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, networking

In chrome developer tools, every time a page loads I click on "Network" tab and see the "record" button active / red. Even if I disable the recording of network traffic, when I refresh the same page or open another website I see that Chrome is recording traffic in the "Network" tab.

When developing big web applications that have A LOT of traffic - 3rd party apis, statics CDNs from Amazon, Google and all the app's assets that must be downloaded like images, js files, css files, etc etc - this "Network" tab works very slowly and my browser gets stuck a lot. This causes my development time to be less productive because I must wait every time I want to check something in the "Networks" tab.

Can I turn the recording off by default? Can the "Record" button be grey and when I want it to start recording I just click on it and start seeing the traffic?

Comment: F12 after your page is loaded,it shouldnt slowdown your website.Or disable network logs and reload your page while dev tools are opened.

Comment: Thanks man, but the solution I'm looking for is a way to disable in the first place all network monitoring, I want to open and see the "grey" circle. Then if I want to monitor the traffic, I can click on the circle and it will turn red and start recording..
I think that's the way a record button is supposed to work actually.

Comment: Have the same problem here. I use SVG-Image-Maps so every icon makes his own request (which is of cause cached, so the actual request will not be made). This adds up to a view thousand requests pretty fast. Would be great to have an option to disable recording by default.

Comment: Same thing here. I'm developing an application which does several requests per second and having the "rec" going on by default is something that slows the browser. Actually in my case, If I don't stop it, it consumes a lot of memory until my computer stop responding. A "temporal" solution doesn't work as I need to refresh the page every now and then. I couldn't find any [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools%3ENetwork+&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Stars+ReleaseBlock+Component+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified) about that.

Comment: Recording is a bad word for it, it's really just showing you the HTTP requests. If you didn't have it on by default, what would you even be checking in the network tab? There'd be nothing to check re: _I must wait every time I want to check something in the "Networks" tab_

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an option to turn off the default recoding BUT you can do the following:

1. Open a new empty tab
2. Hit F12
3. Disable Network Recording
4. Paste the url of your application to the adressbar

This way you don't have to load the page once before disabling network recording, which is your problem from what I understand, because you have a lot of resources loading.

Comment: You probably thought of that before but maybe others who find this question havent.

Answer (score 1):

2018 solution: The only thing that works for me is opening this page:

`chrome://serviceworker-internals/`

And then `Unregister` and `Stop` all workers there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a button in the top left of the Network Panel. It looks like a little red circle, you can hit that to stop recording network events.

I just disabled it, refreshed this page and saw nothing in there. Is something like that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi,thanks for the tip. But what I'm looking for is an option to disable the red record button by default in the first place. This method still makes me load the page once to be able to disable traffic recording and then refresh the page.

Comment: @Alexandre -- if you don't open the F12 tools, the record button isn't doing anything, it's not recording.   That's what I was trying to say.     Once you open it, it's default is "on".    Either don't open F12 tools, or open them before loading the page, turn it off, then load the page.   There is no setting for "when I open F12, have it not start tracking network traffic".

Answer (score 0):

By default, it's not recording anything until you have the F12 tools open (even though the circle is red when you first open it).     If you don't have the F12 tools open, it won't record the history.  When you first open it, if you notice at the bottom, it tells you that nothing has been cached, and refresh the page if you want to see the network traffic.     If, when you open the F12 tools, your site is still doing a lot of traffic, it'll start reporting it at that point, but nothing prior.

I'm pretty dubious that it's the source of your slow-down.    It's really just capturing all the HTTP traffic and saving the request/responses, it's not a lot of work, very little in fact.   The resources/profiles/timelines parts that *can* be more consuming are all off by default.

[image: This is opening F12 tools right after Reddit has finished loading]

Comment: Hi man,
thanks for the tip. But since I'm using this while developing I must have the developer tools open all the time because I use the "Console" tab to see console prints, "Source" tab for debugging javascript code etc.
To leave the developer tools closed till the page is completely loaded can make the flow faster for someone just looking to inspect the "Network" tab. In web development I don't think it's a good solution because we must use all the tools available, specially when the page is loading to check if everything is being loaded and is working properly.

Comment: "I'm pretty dubious that it's the source of your slow-down."  It's trivial to test this. It *is*, without a doubt, the source of the slowdown. My app (in dev app with hundreds of individual files; no bundling implemented yet) takes 5+ seconds longer with network recording enabled. I could close the developer tools, but having it open is the only way to make Chrome completely bypass the cache. I've gotten in the habit of quickly hitting the red button to stop recording, but it re-enables itself when you reload the page. I, like the OP, would like the option to disable recording entirely.